# Comparing key-value pair found at the same index of two dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I want to compare the key-value pair of two dictionaries. The comparison is done in such a way that the first item of the first dictionary is compared against the first item of the second dictionary, the second item with the second item, and goes like this.

The structure of the dictionaries are:

```py
dep_feats = {0: {'Gender': {'Masc'}, 'Number': {'Sing'}, 'Person': {'3'}}, 1: {}, 2: {'Number': {'Sing'}, 'Person': {'3'}}, 3: {'Gender': {'Masc'}, 'Number': {'Sing'}, 'Person': {'3'}, 'Tens': {'Past'}, 'Voice': {'Act'}}, 4: {}}
```

and

```py
head_feats = {0: {'Gender': {'Masc'}, 'Number': {'Sing'}, 'Person': {'3'}, 'Tens': {'Past'}, 'Voice': {'Act'}}, 1: {'Number': {'Sing'}, 'Person': {'3'}}, 2: {'Gender': {'Masc'}, 'Number': {'Sing'}, 'Person': {'3'}, 'Tens': {'Past'}, 'Voice': {'Act'}}, 3: {}, 4: {'Gender': {'Masc'}, 'Number': {'Sing'}, 'Person': {'3'}, 'Tens': {'Past'}, 'Voice': {'Act'}}}
```

```
for i in range(len(dep_feats)):
    for j in range(len(head_feats)):
        if i == j:
            if dep_feats[i].items() == head_feats[i].items():
                print(dep_feats[i].items())
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? The ordering of items in dictionaries was not officially preserved until Python 3.7.

Comment: Please write again your question. What you would like to achieve?

Comment: @AbrGk, I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve since there is no simple case example. Also keep in mind that order insertion is guaranteed since Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your point is to compare in the same key, you should create a set containing the common keys in both dictionaries and then compare their values.

```
common_keys = set(dep_feats).intersection(set(head_feats))

for key in common_keys:
    if dep_feats[key].items() == head_feats[key].items():
        print(dep_feats[key])
```

This way you will reduce the time complexity by removing a nested for loop.

Comment: Wrong. dep and heads are string (keys), not dicts

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota, fixed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `zip()`

```py
for dep, head in zip(dep_feats.items(), head_feats.items()):
    if dep == head:
        print(dep)
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. Consider the case he is not using Python 3.6+. The elements in the dictionary are not going to be sorted, and even if all keys in both dicts are the same, the worst case scenario could be that none of the comparisons are match.

Comment: If they aren't sorted he could sort them using the code ```sorted(dep_feats.items(), key=lambda pair : pair[0])``` to sort the two lists of pairs independently

Comment: I think the main problem is that we need an example of what he wants to achieve...